# Qt, Mysql driver not loaded (windows)

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, qt

Итак, имеется: 
Qt 5.5 
Mysql 5.7 
Попытался подключиться, выдает ошибку "driver not loaded". 
Перекинул файл libmysql.dll и в папку проекта и в Qt - не помогло. 
Решил собрать плагин. Пошел по инструкции. 
код типа:

```
   qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/include" "LIBS+=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/lib/libmysql.lib" mysql.pro
   C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>mingw32-make
```

Вызывает ошибки типа:

```
g++: error: C:/Program: No such file or directory 
g++: error: Files/MySQL/MySQL: No such file or directory
```

Решил упростить и сделал линк пути

```
 C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>mklink /j "c:\ow"    
 "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7" соединение создано для c:\ow «===» C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7
```

Повторил процесс и получил следующее

```
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/ow/include" "LIBS+=C:/ow/lib/libmysql.lib" mysql.pro        
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>mingw32-make 
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory      'C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql' 
g++ -Wl,-s -shared -Wl,-subsystem,windows -Wl,--out-    implib,C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlmysql.a -o     ..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll .obj/release/main.o     .obj/release/qsql_mysql.o .obj/release/moc_qsql_mysql_p.o C:/ow/lib/libmysql.lib     -Ls:/lib -LC:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/lib -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core     .obj\release\qsqlmysql_resource_res.o 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefined reference     to `mysql_num_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_num_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x1ea): undefined reference to `mysql_num_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x217): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_num_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_insert_id@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to `mysql_insert_id@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x618): undefined reference to `mysql_character_set_name@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x889): undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x8a0): undefined reference to `mysql_field_seek@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x8cc): undefined reference to `mysql_field_seek@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x8d7): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x91f): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x951): undefined reference to `mysql_error@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x960): undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xada): undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xb41): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_error@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xb4e): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_errno@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xd00): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_data_seek@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xd11): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_fetch@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xd7e): undefined reference to `mysql_data_seek@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xd8f): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xeb0): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0xef7): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_fetch@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x1137): undefined 22:21:16  reference to `mysql_fetch_lengths@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2278): undefined reference to `mysql_init@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2429): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x25fb): undefined reference to `mysql_set_character_set@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2612): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version@0' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2630): undefined reference to `mysql_thread_init@0' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x27a2): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x288b): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x299e): undefined reference to `mysql_options@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x29cc): undefined reference to `mysql_options@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x29f4): undefined reference to `mysql_options@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2b9e): undefined reference to `mysql_select_db@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2ccf): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2ce6): undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_version@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2d0e): undefined reference to `mysql_options@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2ec4): undefined reference to `mysql_thread_end@0' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x2ecf): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x34c9): undefined reference to `mysql_list_fields@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x3526): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x3535): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x35fa): undefined reference to `mysql_query@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x373a): undefined reference to `mysql_query@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x387a): undefined reference to `mysql_query@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x3af6): undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_version@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x3f83): undefined reference to `mysql_list_tables@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x3fcb): undefined reference to `mysql_data_seek@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x3fd6): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x41d6): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x45ab): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x46a4): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4794): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_result_metadata@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x47c7): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x47e8): undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4805): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_close@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x482b): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x48e4): undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4c4f): undefined reference to `mysql_real_query@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4d40): undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4d65): undefined reference to `mysql_field_count@4'
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4da7): undefined reference to `mysql_affected_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4e5c): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x4efe): undefined reference to `mysql_field_count@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x50d7): undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x50ff): undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5119): undefined reference to `mysql_field_count@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x523b): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5347): undefined reference to `mysql_affected_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x53db): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x55a4): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_prepare@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x55bd): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_param_count@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5627): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_init@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x57ea): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_param_count@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x58bc): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_reset@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5ada): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_param_count@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5af3): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_execute@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5c57): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_affected_rows@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5c87): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_bind_result@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5caa): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_store_result@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5cd8): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_bind_result@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x5d1a): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_param_count@4' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x6075): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_bind_param@8' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x64db): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_attr_set@12' 
.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o:qsql_mysql.cpp:(.text+0x67e9): undefined reference to `mysql_real_escape_string@16' 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:     .obj/release/qsql_mysql.o: bad reloc address 0x4 in section `.data' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
Makefile.Release:81: recipe for target '..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll' failed 
mingw32-make[1]: *** [..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory     'C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql' 
makefile:38: recipe for target 'release-all' failed 
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

Есть идеи что делать теперь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в битности mingw и битности mysql. нужен 32-битный сервер. А затем действовать как здесь указано. все пашет. [MySQL драйвер управления БД сборка и установка](http://kupchyklabs.com.ua/qt-5-mysql-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/)

Answer (score 2):

Путь к `libmysql.dll` нужно либо добавить в переменную окружения `PATH` либо положить рядом с исполняемым файлом. Если Вы скачали готовую сборку Qt, то ничего дополнительно собирать не нужно — уже всё собрано.

Comment: я же написал, я данный файл перекидывал уже всюду и к исполняемым тоже. Результата не дает. Qmysql все также не видно. 
и если что в pro у меня sql написано

Comment: @psy_duck, этого не может быть. Покажите скриншот любой программы, которая показывает наличие dll в процессе. Покажите присутствие _libmysql.dll_ там

Comment: в общем, спасибо за помощь, но деле было в плагине (просто смена битности результата не дала) и его пришлось пересобрать.