# QT драйвера находятся в списке доступных, но пишет что они не установлены

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При попытке запуска выводится это

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Драйвера вроде доступны, но вроде и не загружены

В bin msvc2017_64 (и msvc2015_64) добавлены файлы

```
libmysql.dll
libmysqld.dll
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
```

В файл проекта .pro добавил DEPENDPATH с библиотеками (тут два варианта которые  пробовал)

```
первый:
DEPENDPATH += C:\Qt\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib
DEPENDPATH +=C:\Qt\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include
второй:
DEPENDPATH += C:\Qt\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib
DEPENDPATH +=C:\Qt\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496298/235611

Comment: @AlexanderChernin скачал новый установщик на 32 битную версию, указал в dependpath. Всё так же

Comment: Скопируйте .dll в папку с исполняемым файлом

Comment: @RafaelF, положил libmysql.dll, libmysqld.dll, libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll в C:\Users\admin\Documents\untitled4, не заработало

Comment: Нужно туда где у вас .exe файл создается после компиляции

Comment: @RafaelF. я отредактировал вопрос добавив туда всё, что внутри  папки с .exe

Comment: установите исходные тексты qt  и зайдите отладчиком внутрь библиотеки, там увидите в чём дело